# Why is Visual Studio required to install nuget?

Tags: chocolatey

I just installed chocolate behind proxy

```
$env:chocolateyProxyLocation = 'http://proxy.com:port'
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

and am trying to install nuget package manager

```
choco install nugetpackagemanager
```

Why does nuget require VS? I get this error:

```
 Chocolatey v0.10.13
Installing the following packages:
nugetpackagemanager
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading NugetPackageManager 2.8.60318.667... 100%

NugetPackageManager v2.8.60318.667 [Approved]
nugetpackagemanager package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package NugetPackageManager wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): y

ERROR: Visual Studio is not installed or the specified version is not present.
The install of nugetpackagemanager was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\NugetPackageManager\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - nugetpackagemanager (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\NugetPackageManager\tools\chocol
ateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a link to the actual application that you are trying to install?  NuGet Package Manager is typically an application that was installed into Visual Studio (it later came baked into Visual Studio installation).  As a result, to install this package:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/NugetPackageManager

You will need to have Visual Studio installed, as this tool is designed to work inside Visual Studio.

If you are actually trying to install the NuGet.exe, then you are using the wrong package, and you should instead be using this one:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine

or the NuGet Package Explorer here:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/NugetPackageExplorer

Update:

Regarding the comment:

> The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags.

In this context, PackageManagement is not referring to the NuGet Package Manager, but rather this:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.1.7.0

Which was previously known as OneGet.

Comment: i see, im probably installing the wrong thing then. btw you forgot to paste link i believe :) also i am trying to install nuget because i need this in powershell Install-Module -Name SqlServer . it errors out saying PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider
'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package
has the tags.

Comment: Not sure what happened there, I have updated answer with links that I intended.

Comment: it actually allowed me to install sqlserver module after i installed nuget.exe with chocolatey. no need for https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.1.7.0

Comment: fyi, if i try installing packagemanagement with chocolatey, i get error: ERROR: ERROR: Running ["C:\windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\2\chocolatey\powershell-package
management\10.0.10586.200\PackageManagement_x64.msi" /quiet /norestart ACCEPTEULA=1 ] was not successful. Exit code was
'1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a pac
kage or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed).

Comment: Exactly what command are you running to generate that last error?

Comment: @Cataster In newer versions of Chocolatey, it will give you explicit instructions on what to do with a 1603 error (aka get the MSI Log and review it searching for "Return Value 3"). That will tell you what the issue is on your environment. 9/10 it is a pending reboot.

Comment: @ferventcoder I definitely tried rebooting, as I did read that message, but that didnt help